# mmenu clone for different cscreen sizes

Tags: jquery, media-queries, mmenu

I want to be able to clone my menu so that I can use it with a different ID for larger screen sizes - I can see clone = true in the options, but I don't understand how to use it?

Can anyone expand on the usage of this?

Thanks
Andy

Comment: We'd love to see some code buddy!

Comment: Sorry for being vague! I realised afterwards that the code is automatically generated so all good.